# Adding retrofit into android project

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to try using Retrofit in a new Android project.

I have added the following to my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

I have a POJO called 'Turbine' which looks as follows:

```
public class Turbine {
    String name;
}
```

I have my Endpoint service class:

```
import java.util.List;

import greenapps.objects.Turbine;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

    public interface GreenAppService {
        @GET("turbines/{id}")
        Call<List<Turbine>> turbine(@Path("id") String id);
    }
```

In my main activity in android I have the following code (this is where I want to execute the call and get back my Turbine pojo object filled with data from the backend:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
...
...
...
//Relevant snippet starts here
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API_V1_ENDPOINT)
            .build();

    GreenAppService service = retrofit.create(GreenAppService.class);
    Call<List<Turbine>> turbine = service.turbine("1");
    turbine.enqueue(new Callback<Turbine>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Turbine> call, Response<Turbine> response) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Turbine> call, Throwable t) {

        }
});//Relevant snippet ends here
```

On the `turbine.enqueue` line I am getting the following error:

[image]

I presume the syntax here is wrong somehow, but I don't quite see what is causing the issue.

Also, once this works, how do I get my Turbine object? Is it a case of doing `Turbine t = response.body();`

Comment: A `List<Turbine>` is not a `Turbine`. Hence, a `Call<List<Turbine>>` is not a `Call<Turbine>`. Is your Web service returning a list of turbines, or a single turbine, from the `turbines/{id}` request?

Comment: Hi Commons, it is infact a single, so I have removed the <List> wrapper around it from all areas, and now it looks good!

Comment: I assume @ViktorYakunin's response is not valid here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you defined that you are waiting an Array of Turbine.

```
turbine.enqueue(new Callback<Turbine>()
```

to

```
turbine.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Turbine>>()
```

also you need to update **onResponse** and **onFailure** methods with arraylist.

I strongly suggest you to apply singleton pattern for your `GreenAppService` object.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of singleton pattern.

```
public final class WebService {

   private static GreenAppService sInstance;

   public static GreenAppService getInstance() {
       if (sInstance == null) {
           sInstance = new Retrofit
           .Builder()
           .baseUrl(Constants.API_V1_ENDPOINT)
           .build();
       }

       return sInstance;
   }
}
```

After that we call like

```
WebService
    .getInstance()
    .yourmethod()
    .enqueue()
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you. When you say apply singleton pattern for the GreenAppService object, I am not sure how, considering it is an interface. Got a guide for that?

Comment: I wrote an example for your GreenAppService, check it out. So that we dont have to create GreenAppService each time we want to use it.

Comment: Just fixed formatting, if you having compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to add retrofit in your project with just one click. (one-time setup)

[Retrofit zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1inGDXi48BAo2Y3cnR_szsbQ4dQCAoQGI/view)

1. Extract the file and you will get the “Retrofit” folder inside.
2. Copy this folder following the Android Studio path
   Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\other
3. Restart your Android Studio.
4. Select your project in which you want to add retrofit and find an option below.

**Project > New > Other> Retrofit**

You can see full blog here

https://medium.com/@mestri.vinayak.n/quick-install-retrofit-in-your-android-project-custom-template-a14a6adc77c2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27305485)

Comment: Corrected @BillTür